# Adaptive Bootstrap 3 grid with column that takes up remaining viewport space

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to achieve an effect like this:

[image]

Fixed width adaptive container, two 50% columns. The left column can be constrained by `.container`, but the right column needs to extend outwards to the edge of the viewport.

Is there a correct way of achieving this with the Bootstrap grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is, for the row where the map needs to be added is introduce a containing element (after the .container closing ) and set position to relative.

Then inside that add another container and row which will maintain the current websites structure. make the map column positioned absolute and right:0 so that it takes up all the space of the viewport on the right.

the map colum should have css something like this:

```
.make-absolute {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
```

[see a working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/odjjrtef/15/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your second column a container of your overflowing element

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6"></div>
 <div class="col-md-6 mapContainer">
  <div class="map">
   OVERFLOWING CONTENT
  </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

In the css, turn on the overflow on the container, and give a width to your map.

```
.mapContainer {
  overflow: visible; 
}

.map {
  width:50vw;
}
```

That should do it.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gawOeB?editors=110

Comment: That's a nice idea, however I need `.map` to be smartly sized to fill the remaining viewport space, not extend past it with a fixed width. This concept could work with JS measuring the remaining viewport width, but would prefer a pure CSS solution.

Comment: In that case, use width:50vw for the map. It will take up 50% of the viewport width, which should do just what you want.